Semiclassical defect measures: Must the symbol be real to have measure concentrate on the characteristic surface?
I have been reading Zworski's book on semiclassical analysis and came across the following theorem.
Some setup: $p(x,\xi)$ is a real symbol in $S(\langle \xi\rangle^k)$ for some $k>0$, meaning $p$ and all of its derivatives are bounded above by $\langle\xi\rangle^k=(1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac{k}{2}}$. We also assume $|p(x,\xi)|\geq \langle\xi\rangle^k$ for large enough $\xi$. We then have:

Theorem 5.3: Suppose that $u_h(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ satisfies $||P(x,hD)u_h(x)|| _ {L^2}=o(1)$    with     $||u_h(x)||_{L^2}=1$. Then for any semiclassical defect measure $\mu$ associated to the family $u _h(x)$ we have Spt$(\mu)\subset p^{-1}(0)$.

My question is this: Is the assumption that $p$ is real necessary? I would also like a counterexample if it does turn out to be necessary. I have tried coming up with one myself but haven't been able to.
My motivation for asking this is to see if there is maybe a 'less clever' proof of the above theorem. Zworski proves it by taking another symbol $q$  which avoids the support of some test function $a$ and satisfies $q=1$ on $p^{-1}(0)$. He then considers the elliptic symbol $p+iq$ and goes from there. Obviously this approach does require that $p$ is real. I cannot think of any motivation for this trick beyond "it works", so I would also be grateful if someone could explain why you might think to do this.
Thanks for any help!
